# Does a sine wave always trail behind a cosine wave?

Tags: trigonometry

Given
$$ \sin (\theta) = \cos \Big(\theta - {\pi \over 2} \Big) $$

and since $ \theta = \text{radian velocity * time} = \omega t $, the equation can also be written as

$$ \sin (\omega t) = \cos \Big(\omega t - {\omega \over \omega}{\pi \over 2} \Big) = \cos \Big[\omega \big(t - {\pi \over {2\omega}} \big) \Big]$$

So the phase difference of $ {\pi \over 2 }  $ automatically implies that a sine always trails behind a cosine with a delay of $ {\pi \over {2 \omega}} $ seconds? I wonder which comes first or trail behind the other, but other the given trig relationship I don't find any explanation on which is the "earlier" wave.

Comment: There is no "earlier" wave on $\Bbb R$ unless you impose a constraint on the domain.

Comment: Is this a mathematical version of the Chicken & Egg problem?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire so if I impose a constraint where the sine and cos both starts within the same period of time, will that make the argument valid?

Comment: @cangrejo that's what I was taught and always used to think until I ponder on the time delay due to phase shift ... if time shift = phase shift, there has to be time difference between sine and cosine, and if there's a time difference, then one has to come before the other.

Comment: You got it all backwards. The sine curve isn't behind the cosine by $\frac\pi{2\omega}$ seconds. The sine curve is *leading* the cosine curve by $\frac{3\pi}{2\omega}$ seconds. After all, the only other possibility would be to think that the concept of "leading" vs "trailing" is meaningless for periodic curves.